# Novice: apache-ignite-2.8.1 default-config.xml changing failure

Tags: java, spring, ignite

I changed `default-config.xml` and failed to restart `ignite.sh`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"/>


        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</beans>
```

The error message is below:

```
Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/home/masapon/bin/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/config/default-config.xml, err=Line 32 in XML document from URL [file:/home/masapon/bin/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/config/default-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 47; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 要素'{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property}'で始まる無効なコンテンツが見つかりました。'{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}'のいずれかが必要です。]

The word "無効なコンテンツ" means "Invalid contents".
```

Please show me the correct config file.

I changed default-config.xml to the one below following instruction here,
but failed to start with another error messages.

```
[19:22:53,965][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1965)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1276)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2045)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:659)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@3f362135], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:302)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:943)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1960)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1997)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2099)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
    ... 13 more
[19:22:58] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:37.877]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1067)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:349)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1965)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1276)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2045)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:659)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@3f362135], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:302)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:943)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1960)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1997)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2099)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
    ... 13 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
```

(and far more error messages)

Comment: What did it look like before you changed it?

Comment: Finally, I found that all nodes must be shut down before any node changes to persistence mode. Thank you very much to Vladimir!

Answer (score 0):

Your `xml` configuration is not valid. Property `dataStorageConfiguration` must reside inside `IgniteConfiguration` because it's a field of the corresponding [class](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setDataStorageConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration-). You should add a closing tag to the `ignite.cfg` bean and remove the self-closing tag. Your `xml` will look approximately like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I Couldn't start because of another error as shown below.

Comment: You have an in-memory node running somewhere in your network. The meaningful error message is ```Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0```. Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve with the cluster configuration having persistent and non-persistent nodes?